# Why can't I install VMWare Tools?

Tags: vmware, tools

I am using this guide:

[Installing VMware Tools from the Command Line with the Tar Installer](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_newguest_tools_linux.html#wp1118025).

When I get to the step where I must type:

`tar zxf /mnt/cdrom/VMwareTools-5.0.0-<xxxx>.tar.gz`

I cannot get any further because it doesn't accept my build number which is 528992

What am I doing wrong? I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to install VMWare Tools for Workstation **5.0** on Workstation **8.0** (that's build 528992).

- You need to mount the correct built-in Tools CD with something like *VM...Install VMware Tools* and then install from there.
- [Or you can try the Tools packages for your version available from VMware here.](http://softwareupdate.vmware.com/cds/vmw-desktop/ws/8.0.1/528992/linux/packages/)

Comment: Ok. I was able to do it using a you-tube video. Now I have another problem. I cannot run this virtual machine full screen. It runs in a small box and there is no way to make it bigger. With other OS like Windows and Mac OS X running in WMWare it's no problem, but here I cant see a way to do it.

Comment: If you have other problems, then please create a new question regarding that. Otherwise people won't be able to help you, and others won't be able to find the answer. Also, if anyone answers your question please upvote and "accept".